# Smooth Div Scroll to determine the active element and add an active class

Tags: jquery, scroll, smooth-scrolling

please tell me. How can I track block to which we scrolled slider when you hover over the arrow. Once we dokrutili to a certain slide, add it and the link active class?

While that happened only with the help scrollerOffset, but the event is triggered immediately. I would like all the same for a particular ID ..

Plugin: http://smoothdivscroll.com/

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xmocartx/F5dRj/15/

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
$("div#catalog_gallary").smoothDivScroll({
    autoScrollingMode: "",
    touchScrolling: true,
    mouseOverRightHotSpot: function(eventObj, data) {
        var scrollerOffset=$("#catalog_gallary").smoothDivScroll("getScrollerOffset");
        if(scrollerOffset>1000)
            $('body > ul > li:nth-child(2)').addClass('active');
    }
});
});
```